# Reversing a linked list and printing the result

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, reverse, element

I'm writing a function that takes a linked-list reverses the elements in place, then prints the result. I cannot get it to work properly when I run it; it only prints the first value.

```
typedef struct node {
    ElemType val;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;


struct list_struct {
    NODE *front;
    NODE *back;
};

//reverse elements in list
void lst_reverse(LIST *l) {
    NODE *p = l->front;
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    NODE *current = p;
    NODE *next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    p = prev;

    lst_print(l);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment `p = prev` does not update the front pointer in your `LIST`. When you call `lst_print(l)` you are starting at the old front of the list which is the new back, hence the reason why it will stop after a single iteration.

Instead, you should update the front (and back) of the list with something like:

```
l->front = prev;
l->back = p;
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation that really helped. Makes perfect sense after thinking about it. Thank you again.